# Unable to use example class posted here in my project

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have been trying everything to get this to work, but to no avail. I tried to use the (AutoResizeTextView) posted here: [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/7678343)

1. I created a new class file in my project with the name "AutoResizeTextView" and pasted the above code.
2. Then i opened the main.xml file and put n the following code:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <com.mn.rl.AutoResizeTextView android:id="@+id/tv"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
       </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. in the mainActivity.java file, i have the following code:

   ```
    package com.mn.rl;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;

     public class rlActivity extends Activity {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);

           com.mn.rl.AutoResizeTextView txt =     (com.mn.rl.AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

           txt.setText("Hello");
       }
   }
   ```

I have no errors in the code, and it runs but there is no autoresizing. the text remains the same size. in the xml i have the autoresize textview layout_width and layout_height set to fill parent, yet the font remains small. also tried `txt.resize().`

What am i doing wrong? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

there is a slight possibility that that class is only meant for resizing down. not up.